# CSS display block not working with anchor links

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown-menu. So for this purpose, I've created a div and some anchor links inside, but the `display: block;` is not working. The cursor is default & the anchor does not seem to be a link.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div id="custom-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">View full profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The CSS**:

```
div#custom-wrapper
{
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 38px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
div#custom-wrapper ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
div#custom-wrapper ul li
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#custom-wrapper ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: grey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what you need exataly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display block element works perfect, Just you need to remove padding and margin for **ul** element.

```
 /*** Default CSS Attributes ***/
 #custom-wrapper ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

 /*** Overwrite CSS Attributes ***/
 #custom-wrapper ul {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
 }
```

```css
div#custom-wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 38px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
div#custom-wrapper ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#custom-wrapper ul li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
   }
div#custom-wrapper ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: grey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">View full profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think "ul" element conflict with another element you can do one more thing add "!important" to padding:0 !important; and margin: padding:0 !important;

Comment: That is not the problem of margin or padding .actually that was because of  adding z-index

Comment: Ohh I see, okay I think you might got a solution to your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a padding for `ul`. Remove it:

```
div#custom-wrapper ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not the right way to build a dropdown. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp) (you would need to include Bootstrap library though, which by the way may make your life much easier).

Comment: Really? Add the whole bootstrap library just for a dropdown?

Comment: Dear @kevmc, do you really wish to engage into this discussion? My answer is definitely YES because it has so many features that may make things much easier not only to solve the dropdown issue.